# Include custom source folder for inclusion in maven test phase

Tags: maven

We have a legacy project that needs us to pull in some custom source from a custom location, i.e. were doing this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration><sources><source>src/uom/java</source></sources></configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works great for building and compiling, but this doesn't result in including this special path when we start adding tests in the `/src/test/java/` folder. What happens is `mvm package` fails with "Class not found" while trying to compile the test cases. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration><sources><source>src/uom/java</source></sources></configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>add-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration><sources><source>src/uom/java</source></sources></configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this? The [documentation on this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) is seemingly not that useful.

Comment: _Test cases can't find the custom source_ how do you validate this ?

Comment: I've clarified the text. The test cases won't run because of class not found errors.

Comment: I mean are you launching it via some IDE or via command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to change this:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>add-test-source</id>
    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
    <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals> <!-- was: add--source -->
    <configuration><sources><source>src/uom/java</source></sources></configuration>
</execution>
```